# PHP API allow access from react app

Tags: php, reactjs, amazon-web-services, symfony, amazon-elb

I have PHP application in Symfony 2.8 and its all REST API in ec2
Frontend is hosted in separate EC2. I am using ELB.

Now I want that only my reactjs front should be able to call API endpoint and if other try via curl or postman then it should not work.

Also I want to have some part like /public to open to public so that anyone can access that.

I am not sure if its possible to do at `Symfony` level or `secuirty groups` or `NACL` or `ALB` level.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you can just implement authentication and you reactjs app will only that can access this with the right credentials.

Or you can maybe verify the user-agent. You can create a specific user-agent for your react js app and check it in your endpoint.